# Exception Handling in Play

Tags: akka

I have a master worker which has a superviser to supervise over its child worker.
The child worker throws a IOException which is viewed by the parent who then calls the resume() method of SupervisorStartegy.

Till now the excption is getting thrown, the exception is transferred to the parent, the parent is calling the resume but after that I am getting a timeout exception

```
public class EmailServiceActor extends UntypedActor{
ActorRef actorRef ;

private static SupervisorStrategy strategy =  
           new OneForOneStrategy(3, Duration.create("1 minute"),  
               new Function<Throwable, Directive>() {  
                 @Override  
                 public Directive apply(Throwable t) {  
                   if (t instanceof IOException) {  
                       System.out.println("IO Exception occurred");
                     return restart();  
                   } else if (t instanceof Exception) {  
                     return stop();  
                   } else {  
                     return escalate();  
                   }  
                 }  
               });  

 @Override  
    public void onReceive(Object message) {  
    System.out.println("Received .....");
    if(message instanceof MyLocalMessage){
        System.out.println("received instr from EmailServiceWorker by EmailServiceActor");
        actorRef.tell(message, self());
    }else{
        actorRef = getSender();
    System.out.println("received instr by EmailServiceActor from Application");
    getContext().actorOf(Props.create(EmailServiceWorker.class),"EmailServiceWorker").tell(message, self());
    }
   }  
   @Override  
   public SupervisorStrategy supervisorStrategy() {  
    return strategy;  
  }  

   @Override
  public void preStart() {
 System.out.println("Pre Restart...");
   }

}
```

I also have a child worker

```
public class EmailServiceWorker extends UntypedActor{

 @Override  
   public void onReceive(Object message) throws IOException{  

         System.out.println("received instr by EmailServiceWorker");
         System.out.println("Sending mail");
         FileReader reader = new FileReader("someFile");
         MyLocalMessage myLocalMessage = new MyLocalMessage("Hello");
         getSender().tell( myLocalMessage, getSelf() );
         getContext().stop(getSelf());

 }

 @Override
   public void preStart() {
     System.out.println("Pre Restart");
   }

}
```

There is no such file as "someFile". I am deliberately trying to raise the error.

The controller is given below
        public class Application extends Controller {

```
    //We need the ActorSystem to host our actors as well as to send and receive messages
    static ActorSystem actorSystem = ActorSystem.create( "play" );

    static {
     // Create our local actors
    actorSystem.actorOf( Props.create( MainActor.class ), "MainActor" );
    actorSystem.actorOf( Props.create( EmailServiceActor.class ), "EmailServiceActor" );

    }

    public static Result index() {
    return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static Promise<Result> localHello( String name )
    {
     // Look up the actor
     ActorSelection myActor =
               actorSystem.actorSelection( "user/MainActor" );

     // Connstruct our message
     MyMessage message = new MyMessage( name );

     // As the actor for a response to the message (and a 30 second timeout);
     // ask returns an Akka Future, so we wrap it with a Play Promise
     Future future = ask(myActor, message, 30000);
     Promise promiseValue = Promise.wrap(future);
     Function<Object, Result> function = new Function<Object, Result>() {
         public Result apply(Object response) {
              if( response instanceof MyLocalMessage ) {
                   MyLocalMessage message = ( MyLocalMessage )response;
                   return ok( message.getMessage() );
              }
             return notFound( "Message is not of type MyMessage" );
         }
     };


     Promise<Result> promiseResult = promiseValue.map(function);
     return promiseResult;
    }


    public static Promise<Result> sendMail(){

        ActorSelection emailActor = actorSystem.actorSelection("user/EmailServiceActor");
        Future future = ask(emailActor,"Hello",190000);
        // Look up the actor

        Promise promiseValue = Promise.wrap(future);
        Function<Object, Result> function = new Function<Object, Result>(){
            public Result apply(Object response) {
            return ok("Email is being sent");
       }
        };

        Promise<Result> promiseResult = promiseValue.map(function);
    return promiseResult;

    }


}
```

But when I run the application I get the error

```
        Pre Restart...
        Received .....
        received instr by EmailServiceActor from Application
        Pre Restart
        received instr by EmailServiceWorker
        Sending mail
        IO Exception occurred
        Pre Restart
        [ERROR] [08/12/2014 10:53:13.844] [play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-5] [akka://play/user/EmailServiceActor/EmailServiceWorker] someFile (No such file or directory)
        java.io.FileNotFoundException: someFile (No such file or directory)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Native Method)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:146)
            at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:101)
            at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:58)
            at actors.EmailServiceWorker.onReceive(EmailServiceWorker.java:18)
            at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
            at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:465)
            at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
            at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
            at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
            at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:393)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
            at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)

        [error] play - Cannot invoke the action, eventually got an error: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://play/), Path(/user/EmailServiceActor)]] after [190000 ms]
        [error] application - 

        ! @6j77j81fk - Internal server error, for (GET) [/sendmail] ->

        play.api.Application$$anon$1: Execution exception[[AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://play/), Path(/user/EmailServiceActor)]] after [190000 ms]]]
            at play.api.Application$class.handleError(Application.scala:296) ~[play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
            at play.api.DefaultApplication.handleError(Application.scala:402) [play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
            at play.core.server.netty.PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler$$anonfun$3$$anonfun$applyOrElse$4.apply(PlayDefaultUpstreamHandler.scala:320) [play_2.11-2.3.2.jar:2.3.2]
            at scala.Option.map(Option.scala:145) [scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
        Caused by: akka.pattern.AskTimeoutException: Ask timed out on [ActorSelection[Anchor(akka://play/), Path(/user/EmailServiceActor)]] after [190000 ms]
            at akka.pattern.PromiseActorRef$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(AskSupport.scala:333) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
            at akka.actor.Scheduler$$anon$7.run(Scheduler.scala:117) ~[akka-actor_2.11-2.3.4.jar:na]
            at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:599) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
            at scala.concurrent.BatchingExecutor$class.execute(BatchingExecutor.scala:109) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
            at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:597) ~[scala-library-2.11.1.jar:na]
```

Comment: This can't be all your code.  Where's your controller?

Comment: I have added the controller

Answer (score 0):

Your `EmailServiceWorker` actor never replies to the sender so that `ask` in your controller is never able to complete.